# aria-describedby in an AngularJS site

Tags: angularjs, wai-aria

I am working on an AngularJS app which needs to be aria compliant. It has been flagged that we need to add `aria-describedby` attributes to our input fields which point to th relevent error message element's `id` attribute.

Our form is currently set up as follows (this is sort of pseudo code and there is a form with a name attribute od "form"):

```
<input aria-describedby="" type="text" name="something" ng-model="mySomething" required>
<label for="something">A field for something</label>
<p ng-show="form.something.$dirty" id="validation-something-invalid">
    Please enter a valid something
</p>
<p ng-show="form.something.$pristine" id="validation-something-empty">
    Please enter the something
</p>
```

My problem is that according to the report I need to add individual IDs to each error element (as shown above) and the `aria-describedby` should start out empty and the id of the appropriate error description element should be added into it when the error is relevent. This is proving problematic as trying to write a directive which watches the validity and other states of a model is pretty tough/complicated.

I would like to simplify this (hopefully this will help me to get this done within this sprint) by adding a surrounding element with an id and point aria-describedby directly at it (permanently). I would then use `ng-if` to add remove the errors from the DOM.

The following article suggests that this is valid (in the last section, titled "Methods to provide context sensitive name/description text") https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2015/05/short-note-on-aria-labelledby-and-aria-describedby/

The amended code:

```
<input aria-describedby="validation-messages-something" type="text" name="something" ng-model="mySomething" required>
<label for="something">A field for something</label>
<div id="validation-messages-something">
    <p ng-if="form.something.$dirty">
        Please enter a valid something
    </p>
    <p ng-if="form.something.$pristine">
        Please enter the something
    </p>
</div>
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution has now been tested by our accessibility team and the solution I posted above does work. So, to reiterate, the solution is as follows:

```
<input aria-describedby="validation-messages-something" type="text" name="something" ng-model="mySomething" required>
<label for="something">A field for something</label>
<div id="validation-messages-something">
    <p ng-if="form.something.$dirty">
        Please enter a valid something
    </p>
    <p ng-if="form.something.$pristine">
        Please enter the something
    </p>
</div>
```

I will try to revisit this post as soon as I can to make it less Angular-centric.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a way to implement dynamic feedback with `aria-describedby`, with your implementation you will the face the same issue that I've been trying to solve. If you don't indicate that there are multiple possible error messages, the error message will only get evaluated once, as if it's static (and user will have to move focus to get an updated feedback).

The solution is to set multiple `aria-describedby` values, separated by space. Even though a feedback message may not shown at the moment, the screen reader will aknowledge that it should be read automatically once it's rendered (and everytime it changes, as long as each state is listed).

**Source**: https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2017/07/short-note-on-aria-label-aria-labelledby-and-aria-describedby/

**Screen reader used**: NVDA

Hence the best approach by reusing your example `(note that Angular is not my framework of choice)`:

```
    <label for="some-input">A field for something</label>
    <input id="some-input" aria-describedby="validation-message-dirty validation-message-pristine" type="text" name="something" ng-model="mySomething" required>
    <p id="validation-message-dirty" ng-if="form.something.$dirty">
    Please enter a valid something
</p>
    <p id="validation-message-pristine" ng-if="form.something.$pristine">
    Please enter the something
</p>
```